# Angular - Setting context with createEmbeddedView

Tags: javascript, angular, templates

I'm having a hard time trying to pass context data to my dynamicly created embeded view.

> *Note:* I'm using Angular 2.4.7

Here is what i whant to achieve:

---

In my **DialogPresetComponent** **(dialog-preset.component.html)**:

This component's view contain a bunch of template ready to be used within my dialog framework:

```
<template #presetInfo>
   {{options.description}} // Note this binding ! Here is the problem
</template>
```

Still in this component, i get a ref to those templates like this:

```
@ViewChild('presetInfo', { read: TemplateRef }) presetInfo: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Then, i store this templateRef in a DialogService, so i can access them later, and from somewhere else.

---

In **DialogComponent** **(dialog.component.html)**:

Here is the template of my modal:

```
<div class='c-header'>
</div>
<div class='c-body'>
    <div #container></div>
</div>
<div class='c-footer'>
</div>
```

---

In **DialogComponent** **(dialog.component.ts)**:

In my **DialogComponent** grab a reference to the container like this:

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef }) containerRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

I also define attributes that i want to access from my dynamicly injected template:

```
options: DialogOptions = { title: 'Dialog title' };
```

---

What am i trying to do:

I'm trying to put the template ***#presetInfo*** within the ***#container*** and with the context of my **DialogComponent**

**So finaly, i inject my template in my component giving it the right context:**

In my **DialogComponent** **(dialog.component.ts)**:

```
// Where templateRef is the template previously  defined in DialogPresetComponent
createEmbeddedView( templateRef: TemplateRef<any> ) {
    this.containerRef.createEmbeddedView( templateRef, this );    
}
```

---

The problem come from the fact that the binding **{{options.description}}** in my injected template DO NOT WORK, even when passing the right context ('this' in my case) via createEmbeddedView.

The framework tell me that options is undefined.

What am i missing here ?

There is not a lot of documentation about this 'context' stuff, so i guess i'm not doing it the right way ....

Any clues or hints are welcome !

Thanks !

Comment: Seems you're passing `this` as context. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, that's intentional, i thaught, that passing 'this' whould make all my components members available from within the included template.
Like if my template was part of the component view ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
this.containerRef.createEmbeddedView( templateRef, {$implicit: {description: 'some description'} } );
```

```
<template #presetInfo let-options>
   {{options.description}} // Note this binding ! Here is the problem
</template>
```

If you pass an object with a property `$implicit` then just `let-xxx` is enough to make the `$implicit` value available as `xxx` within the template.

For other properties you need `let-yyy="someProp"` to make it available within the template as `yyy`.

Comment: Damn that work !
Thanks a lot, where did you get the documentation concerning this $implicit attribute and the rules you explains ? 
From the angular source code ?

Comment: I saw it in discussions in Angular2 GitHub issues or Pull Requests. Don't remember exactly, but I was following Angular2 development quite closely the whole 2016.

Comment: Nice one ! Thanks

Comment: It's mentioned **very** briefly here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Comment: That's brief :)

Comment: But such things got me going, I then checked in the source and so I got it working eventually :D

Comment: This could be a nice subject for a small **medium.com** post :)

Comment: Writing text is not my thing. I prefer SO ;-)

Comment: Why do you think so?)

Comment: Hi @yurzui who? what are you referring to? Me not wanting writing text? I find writing text quite exhausting and don't enjoy it like writing code.

Comment: Yes, i asked about you)

Comment: Ok. Tried a blog a few years ago, was nice to investigate google analytics stats and stuff, but lost interest in writing soon :D

Comment: I agree that it's exhausting but you can collect whole your knowledge in one place. But seems SO is its place for you)

Comment: Exactly, SO's gamification totally gets me :D

Comment: Anyway http://take.ms/x9pZM here is where `context` for embedded view is compiled

Comment: I wrote `let-options="options"` and passed `this` as context

Comment: @yurzui hey there, but how can i get these options if i use it as sctructural directive? for example: 
<div 
      *dropdownMenu
       outsideDropdown> </div>

Where dropdownMenu creates embedded view